# How to export the cleaned_data variable to the next layer using the in-memory data structure?

Tags: python, scrapy

I built a scraper to scrape from a website, the scraper works completly fine. I used to store data into two separate json files which are raw_data.json and cleaned_data.json. But I am currently trying to merge the scraper with my company's framework, and in the framework process there is no local storage. So I'm trying to export the data using the in-memory data structure which is passing the raw_data and cleaned_data variables to the next step of action. I already made the scraper a package. So the importing worked well, but when I tested to run it, the output is just empty. I'm stuck on this issue for a few days already, so is there a way out?

All I want to achieve is to export those two variables raw_data and cleaned_data into run_spider.py when they are complete using the dispatcher maybe?

Here is a part of my pipelines.py

```
class RawDataPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_data = []
    
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # Basic data validation: Check if the scraped item is not empty
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter.get('project_source'):
            self.raw_data.append(adapter.asdict())
        return item
    
    def close_spider(self, spider):
    
        """
        with open('raw_data.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(self.raw_data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        """
        spider.crawler.signals.send_catch_log(signal=spider.custom_close_signal, raw_data=self.raw_data)
        return self.raw_data

class CleanedDataPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.cleaned_data = []
        self.list_dic = {}
    
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        cleaned_item = self.clean_item(item)
        self.cleaned_data.append(cleaned_item)
        return item
    
    def close_spider(self, spider):
    
        # Convert values to list for keys in list_dic
        for key in self.list_dic:
            for cleaned_item in self.cleaned_data:
                self.convert_to_list(cleaned_item, key)
        
        #with open('cleaned_data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        #    json.dump(self.cleaned_data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
    
        # Log list_dic
        #spider.log("List_dic: %s" % json.dumps(self.list_dic, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    
        spider.crawler.signals.send_catch_log(signal=spider.custom_close_signal, cleaned_data=self.cleaned_data)
    
        return self.cleaned_data
```

And this is the python scripts where I start the spider and tried to get the data when the spider is closed

```
def spider_closed(signal, sender, **kwargs):
    # Access the data after the spider is closed
    raw_data = RawDataPipeline().raw_data
    cleaned_data = CleanedDataPipeline().cleaned_data

    print("Raw Data:", raw_data)
    print("Cleaned Data:", cleaned_data)


def run_spider():
    # Create a CrawlerProcess
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)

    # Connect the spider_closed signal to your callback function
    dispatcher.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    # Add your spider to the process
    process.crawl(NieuwbouwspiderSpider)

    # Start the crawling process
    process.start()


run_spider()
```

This doesn't work, printed results are just empty. Is there a solution?

Comment: `close_spider()` doesn't suppose to return anything.
You can print the items after the spider closes. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532113/how-to-import-urls-from-spider-to-spider/70533884#70533884) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284426/how-to-export-scraped-items-as-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-scrapy/70287780#70287780) help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution using the dispatcher.send with singnals.close_spider.